# MacBook Pro 2013 - new hard drive installed - strange startup screen

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, install

I just installed a new hard drive in my MacBook Pro 2013 model. It's exactly the same make as the original drive. Just to be sure, I pre-formatted it as Mac OS Extended using a SATA-USB adapter cable attached to my other MacBook.

When I switch it on, all I get is a flashing folder symbol (see pic). I can't get to Recovery Mode by holding down Option+R in the usual way.

Any ideas?

Cheers, StuC

[image: MacBook Pro startup screen]

Comment: Is the new hard drive empty?

Comment: Yup - completely blank. I connected it to my other MacBook using the SATA-USB cable, then used DU to erase & reformat it.

Comment: You are going to have to boot to [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) to download macOS. Either that or download macOS to the the other MacBook and [make a USB macOS flash drive installer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). Boot from the flash drive installer on this Mac to install macOS. BTW, to install Mojave (or newer), you will need to format APFS.

Comment: I wonder if that was a typo. Try booting using Cmd+R? — See "[If you can't start up from macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314#internet)" at the bottom.

Comment: Duh - sorry. Typo, as you say! TVM for the support link - I'll have a look

Comment: You know, this follow up page makes it clearer. I didn't know this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904 — At the top below the heading: "Start up from macOS Recovery". Apparently `alt+cmd+r` is for upgrade...

Comment: Just tried all three options but none work. Might have to make a visit to the apple store. That's gonna cost...

Comment: Yea. I don't know. I just watched [a youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCUY0eYrUn4) with someone installing new drive and using `cmd+r` to boot to recovery mode...

Comment: Cmd/R will try to boot from local recovery, but if one isn't available, it will switch automatically to Internet Recovery. The only way that would fail is if it can't find a network, which would give an Err No. under the globe icon. [It shouldn't ever drop to the ? folder if done that way.] Additionally, I'd fully format the drive again from Recovery once you get there - it will add 3 extra hidden partitions if it's to be the new boot drive & I'm not certain exactly when it will do that.

Comment: Cheers guy - your help much appreciated. I've used a LAN cable to connect to the router, so I know the internet connection is robust (and I'm using it over wifi on my other laptop to type this). No spinning globe though... only the flashing folder with "?".

Comment: Just found this too... https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204323

Comment: Try Cmd/Opt/R just in case it's not switching to Internet Recovery automatically, & do it right as the chimes are sounding & hold them until something happens. You can't hang on too long, but you can let go too early. [& you haven't reached the point at which your last link is relevant - you know why it won't boot... the drive is empty ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin, shouldn't it go to the recovery mode either way? You just wouldn't be able to do anything without an internet connection, right? He's not able to boot into it at all.

Comment: @Joonas - The precise path through the variety of options depends on the age of the Mac & what OS was last on it. Trying both Cmd/R & Cmd/Opt/R is a catch-all.

Comment: @Tetsujin, but is there any situation where the recovery mode won't show up without an internet connection?

Comment: TVM guys - bit of a head-scratcher! I've tried all the various key combos, but no luck. LAN connection is robust, because I've just tried it on my other laptop too.

Comment: Try the USB flash drive method. Or, use you other Mac to create a WiFi hotspot and try booting to Internet Recovery via WiFi. As for the Ethernet, are you sure the router is not prohibiting the assignment of an address to your Mac?

Comment: I would like to say thanks to all for the advice - I've tried the lot (even the flash drive - thanks David), and can't get past the flashing folder "?". I've finally thrown in the towel & gone to the nearest apple store. They booked it in for a diagnostic (there's a charge, of course), but at least I'll find out what's going on. I'll let you know if anything useful comes back